# PyCharm Highlight Issue

Tags: pycharm

Please take a look at the diagram below.

[image]

As you can see the highlight is not being restricted line by line. To be honest, I don't even know what to call it. How do I revert back to the original highlighting thingy... I tried googling but I don't even know what to search for a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PyCharm help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d147546e330):

> **Toggling between line and column selection modes**
>
> To toggle between the line and the column selection modes, do one of
>   the following:
>
> - On the main menu, choose Edit | Column Selection Mode.
> - On the context menu of the editor, choose Column Selection Mode.
> - Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.